# JQuery load() will break facebook like button/comment box. How to workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, load

I am coding a big website but I have cut down my problem into the following tiny html file:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3224566/test.html

The problem is that if I (re)load with JQuery a content that features a facebook code, the latter won't appear, even if I reload the script (leading to a duplication of that all.js script, which is another issue).

How can I fix this?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`FB.XFBML.parse()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after you load the new content

```
function loadPage() {
  $('#test').load('test.html #test', function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse( );
  }).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

---

Note, that loading a fragment with id **test** in a div with id **test** will create multiple (*two*) elements with the same id (*nested in each other*) in the page, which should never happen as it is invalid.

To avoid this use the more verbose [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method

```
$.get('test.html', 
        function(data) {
                    var temp = $('<div>').html(data).find('#test');
                    $('#test').html(temp.html());
              }
      );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just picking up the double id **test** thing, how would it be most elegant to solve?