# Why does Facebook comment box not load after calling jQuery.load?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-load

I have used `jQuery.load()` method in my wordpress site to load next and previous post. Script is working fine but the problem is when the next or previous post loads the social media button like Facebook or Tweet button, but Facebook comment box does not load.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345787/jquery-load-will-break-facebook-like-button-comment-box-how-to-workaround) but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that using

```
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
        #twitter and google code goes here
    });
```

which load after the content. its fine and working properly